# How to set focus to next TextField in view by hitting button?

Tags: ios, swift

There was many guys who meet problem with absence of *Done* button in numeric keyboard for iOS and there are many solutions to do it. I create this button but I cant find way to set focus on next text field by hit on this button. In my case there code that generates Table with TableViewCells. Thats why common idea to create reference to every Cell (anyway there are many cells). Every TableViewCell include ContentView and ContentView include TextField.
As result my custom *Done* button should behave like Return button in standard keyboard. By the way there method in ***textFieldShouldReturn*** that change focus but ***textFieldShouldReturn*** invoked on built-in *Return* button.
P.S. Im new in Swift.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After I carefully rechecked existing jump function I put it into **textFieldDidEndEditing** event. Inside Done function (doneAction in Nasir`s example) I put *self.endEditing(true)*

Answer (score 1):

**Note**: I have created a sample project where the next button functionality is implemented. You can find the project: https://github.com/nasirky/uitableview-form

You can add a toolbar with a done button to the UITextField **inputAccessoryView**. Here is an example

```
override func viewDidLoad() { 
  super.viewDidLoad()
  textField.inputAccessoryView = getToolbar() 
  } 

func getToolbar() -> UIToolbar {
   let toolBar = UIToolbar(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.width, height: 40))
  let doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: .plain, target: self, action:#selector(doneAction(_:)))
  toolBar.setItems([doneButton], animated: false) 
  return toolBar 
}

func doneAction(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
 /* Code for dismissing keyboard or moving focus to next UITextField */
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for prompt answer. Your idea is quite elegant but If doneAction(_:) refers to some method - I have approximately the same idea at the moment. In my "DoneAction" I just use _italic_self.resignFirstResponder()_italic_ that works fine. I guess idea is to transfer this state to next TextField. I have some "jump" function that works for normal keyboard, because it invoked in textFieldShouldReturn (That is result of Return button). Looks like I could extend this behavior for my custom button. Another approach is to implement this behavior in doneAction method, looks more hard .

Comment: doneAction is a method where you write the code to transfer the code to next textfield. If you need help in your context, I can provide you with sample code

Comment: Yes please, it would be very kind from your side. Just in case I would like to add that I use extension UITextField where I have 2 methods, on add button to numeric keyboard and other provide Done action. All this implemented in View for TableViewCell.

Comment: Can you please share your the code for the 2 methods you ate talking about and also cellForRowAtIndexPath

Comment: Thank you very much for your participation! I found solution. Description below.

Comment: You are hiding the keyboard. If you want to move focus to next textfield, I can send you some code for that